# gnome-keyring warning on print JAVA

Tags: java, printing, warnings, gnome-keyring-daemon

I'm trying to print a barcode image, but when the program executes the .printDialog() I get the following warning on the console:

```
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-y4THJ1/pkcs11: No such file or directory
```

And when I hit the print button, I get null.

Here is the code:

```
    private void jButton1MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printJob.setPrintable(new Printable()
    {
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
            if (pageIndex != 0) {
                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }
            graphics.drawImage(imagen, 0, 0, imagen.getWidth(null), imagen.getHeight(null),   null);
            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    });
    if (printJob.printDialog()) {
        try {
            printJob.print();
        } catch (Exception prt) {
            System.err.println(prt.getMessage());
        }
    }


}
```